# How to delete multiple key from digitalocean space object storage?

Tags: digital-ocean, object-storage, cloud-object-storage

I am trying to delete multiple object once by using delete_objects. But i am getting an error. I didn’t found any solution regarding to this issue.

```
client = boto3.client("s3", **config)

        response = client.delete_objects(
                    Bucket=BUCKET,
                    Delete={
                        'Objects': [
                            {
                                'Key': 'asdasd1.png',
                            },
                            {
                                'Key': 'asdasd1.png',
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    RequestPayer='requester'
                )
```

I get an error like this:

```
An error occurred (NotImplemented) when calling the DeleteObjects operation: Unknown
INFO:     127.0.0.1:46958 - "DELETE /image/ HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you, it's another way to do it

```
def cleanup_from_s3(bucket, remote_path):
    s3_contents = list_s3(bucket, remote_path)

    if s3_contents == []:
        return

    for s3_content in s3_contents:
        filename = s3_content["Key"]

        s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key="{0}/{1}".format(remote_path, filename))
```